# How to generate bharat qr code in php with razorpay payment gateway

Tags: php, razorpay

```php
<?php

    require('config.php');
    require('razorpay-php/Razorpay.php');
    session_start();

    use Razorpay\Api\Api;

    $api = new Api($keyId, $keySecret);
    //$order = $api->order->create(array('receipt' => '123', 'amount' => 100, 'payment_capture' => 1, 'currency' => 'INR'));
    //print_r($order);
    $bharatQR = $api->VirtualAccount->create(
        array('receivers' =>
            array('types' =>array('qr_code')
            ),
            'description' => 'First QR code',
            'amount_expected' => 100,
            'payment_capture' => 1,
            'currency' => 'INR',
            'notes' =>
                array('receiver_key' =>  $key)
        )
    );

    //$razorpayOrder = $api->order->create($bharatQR);
    //$razorpayOrderId = $razorpayOrder['id'];
    //$_SESSION['razorpay_order_id'] = $razorpayOrderId;
    //$displayAmount = $amount = $orderData['amount'];
?>
```

Error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Razorpay\Api\Errors\BadRequestError: The requested URL was not found on the server. in F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\Request.php:123 Stack trace: #0 F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\Request.php(90): Razorpay\Api\Request->processError(Array, 400, Object(Requests_Response)) #1 F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\Request.php(44): Razorpay\Api\Request->checkErrors(Object(Requests_Response)) #2 F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\Entity.php(58): Razorpay\Api\Request->request('POST', 'https://api.raz...', Array) #3 F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\Entity.php(14): Razorpay\Api\Entity->request('POST', 'virtualAccounts...', Array) #4 F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\VirtualAccount.php(9): Razorpay\Api\Entity->create(Array) #5 F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\qrcode.php(20): Razorpay\Api\VirtualAccount->create(Array) #6 {main} thrown in F:\wamp64\www\inventrymanagement\razorpay\razorpay-php\src\Request.php on line 123

Comment: beautify your code...

Comment: Update your SDK and then hit

Comment: Hello @sateesh-roy, Have you got any solution for this ?